# Участники сообщества в стим

Tags: steam-web-api

Как узнать участников сообщества в стим через стим веб апи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен именно запрос к api, то можете делать такой запрос:

```
 http://steamcommunity.com/groups/gid/memberslistxml/?xml=1
```

где gid - это id группы

Если вы используете, например `nodejs`, то можно воспользоваться методом `getMembers` модуля https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity